# Why does a Pydantic.BaseModel derived class can not instantiate a contained class?

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

Using Python3

I have the following code:

```
    class Suitcase():
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 32


class Cargo(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = "Mine"
    suitcase: Optional[Suitcase] = None


    def check(self):
        cargo.suitcase = Suitcase()
```

at some point in time I run the following code:

```
cargo = Cargo()
print(cargo)
```

the error I get is

```
class Cargo(BaseModel):
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 204, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 488, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 419, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 539, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 801, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators
  File "pydantic/validators.py", line 723, in find_validators
RuntimeError: no validator found for <class '__main__.Suitcase'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
```

Is it because a BaseModel derived class can not contain other classes?

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

A pydantic model can contain other classes. In the pydantic documentation you'll find this under [Model Config](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/), with further information on custom types [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#arbitrary-types-allowed):

> `arbitrary_types_allowed`
>
> whether to allow arbitrary user types for
> fields (they are validated simply by checking if the value is an
> instance of the type). If False, RuntimeError will be raised on model
> declaration (default: False). See an example in Field Types.

`Suitcase` is a custom type, so you should configure `Cargo` to allow arbitrary types. You have to define a config for your class, and set `arbitrary_types_allowed = True`:

```
class Suitcase():

    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 32


class Cargo(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = "Mine"
    suitcase: Optional[Suitcase] = None
        
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


    def check(self):
        cargo.suitcase = Suitcase()
```

You could also add a custom validator for the field `Cargo.suitcase`, example:

```
class Cargo(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = "Mine"
    suitcase: Optional[Suitcase] = None
        
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

    @validator('suitcase')
    def validate_suitcase(cls, v):
        assert v.weight <= 32

    def check(self):
        cargo.suitcase = Suitcase()
```

Disclimer: Code not tested